# Submitting multiple forms using iframe with single submit button

Tags: jsp, iframe

I am developing application using spring mvc framework. I have one requirement where in I should be able to submit multiple forms from single jsp page. For this purpose, I am using multiple Iframes each Iframe will contain one form each. Now problem is how to submit all the form which is in different Iframes(but same parent jsp page) at once with using only one submit button.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to accomplish what you want would be to use JavaScript to suck in all the various iFrame form data into one form and submit that.  If you were going the other way (trying to post from the parent frame to the child), I think you can use the target attribute on the form element to determine which frame to load the results to.